# Are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p^2+1$ is divisible by a prime greater than $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I've been trying to come up with an elementary construction, but to no avail. Are more advanced tools needed?

If we consider an analog to this question where we do not require p to be prime (i.e. if there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ is divisible by a prime greater than $n$), then the question becomes much easier:

Pick a prime $p$ that is $1$ mod $4$, and let $g$ be a generator of mod $p$. Then choosing $n\equiv g^{\frac{p-1}{4}}$ mod $p$, with $n<p$, works.

Comment: The answer is apparently yes if we don't require $p$ to be prime: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/257082/the-sequence-n21-and-semiprimes

Comment: Perhaps you could post the constructions you've tried?

Comment: Seems @RobertIsrael answered the question on mathoverflow,maybe he has more insights on this problem though not quite sure(this should link him to this post).

Comment: @kingW3 Not only Robert Israel answered it, also Myshkin.

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're right but I can't seem to find Myshkin profile while Robert Israel has 248k reputation here

Comment: @kingW3 Could you link me to RobertIsrael's answer? I can't seem to find this question on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Richard I meant to the answer that Robert Israel posted here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/257082/the-sequence-n21-and-semiprimes my mistake should've phrased my comment better.I've thought if he answered that question maybe he knows the answer to this one also,that's why I said not quite sure.Hope I linked to him right,if I did he should see this post.

Comment: I tried searching for this sequence in the OEIS, but I don't think I've found anything relevant, other than *maybe* this one: https://oeis.org/A280930

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iwaniec [has shown](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/download/PPN356556735_0047/PPN356556735_0047___LOG_0016.pdf) through sieve methods the existence of infinite values of $n$ such that $n^2+1$ is the product of $\leq 2$ primes. This is, as far as I know, the closest claim to Landau's conjecture about the existence of infinite primes of the form $n^2+1$ (still an open problem), together with the results of Iwaniec, Friedlander and Heath Brown about the existence of infinite primes of the form $a^4+b^2$ (like $2017$) or $a^3+2b^3$. Inserting the constraint $n\in\mathcal{P}$ into Iwaniec' approach and exploiting Vinogradov's estimates about exponential sums over primes should be possible but quite a technical challenge. On the other hand, it looks highly unrealistic that $\omega(p^2+1)\geq 3$ for every prime large enough: I believe the opposite can be shown by proving a lack of correlation between the arithmetic functions $\omega$ and $\chi$, with $\chi$ being a Legendre symbol.

Comment: This seems correct. However, I'm wondering if there might be a more elementary solution? The full power of Iwaniec's work seems overkill.

Comment: @Richard: I think this problem is very far from being solvable with elementary techniques, despite its appearance.